# If I store a member as an object, will I incur an object copy during constuction?

Tags: c++, pointers, dependency-injection

If the constructor for `Door` looks like this:

```
Door::Door(Doorknob doorknob) : m_doorknob(doorknob) { }
```

Then you would instantiate a `Door` like this:

```
Doorknob doorknob;
Door door(doorknob);  // Does an object copy of doorknob occur here?
```

It seems like if you store `Doorknob` as a pointer, you can explicitly avoid the copy:

```
Door::Door(Doorknob * doorknob_ptr) : m_doorknob_ptr(doorknob_ptr) { }
```

Instantiate `Door` like this:

```
Door door(new Doorknob);
```

But now you have to make sure to `delete doorknob` inside `Door`'s destructor, which seems ugly.

What is the preferred approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More important than minimizing the number of copy constructor calls is that your code correctly models the problem space.

Door owns the doorknob; i.e. the lifecycle of DoorKnob is the same as that of Door.  Thus, Door should manage the lifecycle of Doorknob.

The second solution is not be preferred for that reason.  You are relying on the client to manufacture the Doorknob object, which you then store a pointer to, which is a violation of [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

Your first solution is acceptable, but as you note, as the problem of making an unnecessary copy of the Doorknob object, since copies as a parameter.

The ideal solution is to have contructor take in a reference, as @pingw33n's solution does.   Or, since it may not make sense to construct a Doorknob outside of a door, have your Door constructor create the Door.

Comment: My concern with passing in Doorknob as a reference is that potentially Doorknob can go out of scope before Door does.  (For example, if Door was declared on the heap and Doorknob was declared on the stack -- this would be a bad thing.)  Perhaps the answer is simple "don't do that" -- but at this point, I am already "new"-ing the Door...so it seems like I need to "new" the Doorknob as well.

Comment: I was imagining your constructor would then make a copy of the Doorknob passed into it -- than the only copy is the one you need.

Answer (score 5):

Better approach is to pass with const reference:

```
Door::Door(const Doorknob& doorknob) : m_doorknob(doorknob) { }
```

Otherwise a copy of `Doorknob` will be passed to constructor and used as parameter for `m_doorknob` constructor.

Comment: Does it not remain a copy while constructing m_doorknob? AFAIK, m_doorknob(doorknob) calls the the copy constructor Doorknob(const Doorknob&)...

Comment: If you define m_doorknob just of type Doorknob, then a copy construction will take place. If you define m_doorknob of type Doorknob &, then your member variable will hold a reference to the passed in Doorknob.